# Zoom in a panel c#

Tags: c#, panel

Im creating a small map for a cemetery and I want to zoom in and zoom out to the map. So my idea is to resize all the content of the panel which is buttons.
My code is here:

```
  foreach (Control btn in this.panel3.Controls)
        {
            if ((btn) is Button)
            {
                btn.Width += 10;
                btn.Height += 10;
            }
        }
```

is there any other way to do it? I am not satisfied because it doesn't look like zoom in or a way to may it more like zoom in. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using a `ScaleTransform`

Comment: Do you need to use WinForms? Scaling / rotating forms works much better with WPF.

Comment: @NineBerry I need to use WinForms.

Answer (score 1):

Your code only *zooms in* the buttons separately. What you may need is to *stretch* the **whole area** of buttons. Something like this (I haven't tested):

```
foreach (Button btn in panel3.Controls.Where(c => c is Button).Cast<Button>())
{
    const double zoom = 1.1;

    //increase position
    btn.Left = Convert.ToInt32(btn.Left * zoom);
    btn.Top = Convert.ToInt32(btn.Top * zoom);

    //increase size
    btn.Width = Convert.ToInt32(btn.Width * zoom);
    btn.Height = Convert.ToInt32(btn.Height * zoom);
}
```

Comment: Also, this does not enlarge font size, you may have to do that manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Scale` method of the `Panel` to zoom in and out the contents of the panel.

```
private void buttonZoomIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cemetaryPanel.Scale(new SizeF(1.1f, 1.1f));
}

private void buttonZoomOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cemetaryPanel.Scale(new SizeF(0.9f, 0.9f));
}
```